# SQL Server and indexes on history data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with 10 million rows, it is the history of customer balances by date.

There are two indexes by `(balance_date, customer_code)` and by `(customer_code, balance_date)` as I access the table by date/all customers and by customer/all dates.

Question is: there's only one row per date/customer, is there a benefit of defining any of the two indexes as unique, or it's better if they are not unique? I'm interested in gaining better performance when I query the table, I don't care much about the insert.

Comment: There is not a gain in efficiency by declaring unique index.  There is a gain in data integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a benefit of defining any of the two indexes as unique, or it's better if they are not unique?

Yes, but very small.  A unique index can be narrower, so more keys can fit on each non-leaf page.

A non-unique index has the row locator (clustered index key columns or rowid) added to the index key columns.  For a unique index the row locator is only present on the leaf pages.

You should probably make one of these indexes the clustered index, possibly with ROW or PAGE compression, or make the table a clustered columnstore.

Answer (score 0):

Having Unique/ Non Unique index depends on the data you have. If you have composite unique value, you can use unique index which is good in performance compared to non unique index. Go through below links for better understanding,

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=unique-vs-non-unique-index

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_index_unique_vs_non_unique.htm

Comment: those are Oracle links, I'm asking about SQL Server

Comment: Its not specific to Oracle, its common lecture on index available in Oracle site.